# Spring - show git commit ID on custom health endpoint

Tags: spring

I am trying to show the Git version info (branch, commit etc) on my custom health endpoint.

I tried using `management.info.git.mode=full` + `git-commit-id-plugin` but there is no direct way to extract the git info into a Java class. If there is, this will be the ideal way.

I also tried the same `git-commit-id-plugin` with Value annotations in my Java class like so `@Value("${git.commit.id}")` but Spring can't find the property values. I see the `git.properties` file created in the target dir.

What am I missing here? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to configure PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer bean so that we can able to access the property file generated by the plugin, Please use the below code for your reference,

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propsConfig 
          = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propsConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("git.properties"));
        propsConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propsConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propsConfig;
    }
```

then in your custom health check class, you can use,

> @Value("${git.commit.id}")
>       private String commitId;

I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Great, thanks! This works with a minor modification of adding doulbe quotes to the property string as follows: `@Value("${\"git.commit.id\"}")`. By the way, was this found in the official docs?

Comment: @john Glad to hear from you. I didn't find any information from docs. But I am using this code in my project and it is working so good so for.

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Boot 2 you can get this information using `git-commit-id-plugin` in **info** endpoint. This is how you can configure it 
**POM File**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Sample Response** http://localhost:8080/actuator/info

```
{ 
"git":{ 
"branch":"some-name",
"commit":{ 
"id":"ef569c2",
"time":1579000598.000000000
}
},
"build":{ 
"artifact":"xxx",
"name":"xxxx",
"time":1579020527.139000000,
"version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
"group":"xxxx"
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easies way is to use the commit plugin:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.build.generate-git-info

It generates git.properties. Then Spring autoconfiguration jumps in. When git.properties is available in the classpath, it creates GitProperties bean:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.info.git-commit-information

Simply inject GitProperties to your bean and use it.